# Transposing the columns and organazing unstructured csv files with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have too many messy csv files and I am trying to extract information from them. There are random number of unnecessary columns at the beginning of each file. However, the columns that I am interested in are always have the same index. Let me explain in it through an example:

```
RandomInfo XX
Random2    ZZ
Random3    VV
Random4    KK

Companyname:      Apple
                  VisitsMay  ImpressionsMay VisitsApril ImpressionsApril...
Information         
   International    100         250            90          260  
   Local            10          22             12          26
   With Proxy       5           12             8           16
```

I want to convert this to:

```
Companyname  Month                 International    Local With Proxy
Apple        VistsMay               100             10      5
Apple        ImpressionsMay         250             22      12
Apple        VisitsApril            90              12      8
Apple        ImpressionsApril       260             26      16
```

[Example files here](http://www.filedropper.com/newsdownload)

Comment: Is the first one a txt file or a representation of a pandas dataframe?

Comment: It is also pandas dataframe

Comment: And how do you build it? I mean, is not a table, those random stuff on top does not fit with the table below

Comment: That is the problem, I could say skip some columns, but I don't know how many columns I need to skip each time...

Comment: Ah, ok. So what you have posted is _not_ the pandas dataframe, is the content of the txt file which should be converted into a pandas dataframe.

Comment: It is in csv format, I posted some example files, please check the update :)